# How can I pass an Option value along?

Tags: f#

I am wondering if there is a way to pass an Option value along from the matching pattern without recreating it?

```
var funA x = Some(x)
var funB x = 
   match funA x with
   | Option(y) -> Option(y) // <---- Recreating the Option value. Can I return the very same one?
   | _ -> failwith "Whatever"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pattern match on an option and return it only when it is `Some` (and do something else if it is `None`), then you can use the `as` construct in pattern matching:

```
let funB x = 
  match funA x with
  | Some _ as optY -> optY
  | _ -> failwith "Whatever"
```

Although this function does not look very useful to me - why return the value as option when you check to make sure that it is `Some` and throw exception otherwise? The return type is `option 'a` but, in fact, you could always return just `'a` value, so there is no point in using `option`...

It is quite likely that there is a nicer solution to your problem - it depends on what exactly you are trying to do. Have a look at the functions in the `Option` module - there might be something that captures what you need.

Comment: This example is oversimplified and doesn't make much sense as written. In the real situation the value is being checked and created with a composition of functions where the outer layers only result to None (validators) and the inner-most creates Some. So on its way out the result from the innermost doesn't need to be recreated at each level  but rather re-returned :)